# Error 4 'DateRange' is a 'variable' but is used like a 'method'

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

This code is being converted over from vb.net and I don't know vb.net very well so i am using the telerik online vb.net to c# converter.

I don't understand why this is giving me an error...

```
string[] DateRange = this.cboPayPeriods.SelectedItem.Text.ToString().Replace(" ", "").Split('-');

while (Convert.ToDateTime(DateRange(0)) <= Convert.ToDateTime(DateRange(1)))
```

It will not build and says

'DateRange' is a 'variable' but is used like a 'method'

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 2):

In C#, arrays are referenced with `[` and `]` not `(` and `)`.  Change it like this:

```
while (Convert.ToDateTime(DateRange[0]) <= Convert.ToDateTime(DateRange[1]))
```

BTW, this is the mistake everyone makes when going from VB to C#.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

change `DateRange(0)` to `DateRange[0]`

Looks like you are using VB syntax instead of C#

Answer (score 1):

`DateRange` is a Array, you access an array via indexer via brackets `[]` in C# instead of round brackets `()` in VB.NET.

So this should work:

```
while (Convert.ToDateTime(DateRange[0]) <= Convert.ToDateTime(DateRange[1]))
```